# Scenarios when to use closures

Tags: c#, closures

I've played with closures a bit in C# and even written them in production-spec apps, however, nothing has really shouted at me that this problem *must* be, or can *only* be, solved with the use of a closure.

Is there any problem where closures are particularly useful for solving? Also, is there any gotcha with closures in C# 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that closures are a compiler feature rather than a platform feature, there's nothing which *can't* be done with them.

You can write all the code which the compiler uses by hand (well, with a few exceptions when it comes to expression trees, and the compiler has access to some IL instructions which aren't exposed by the language).

However, you'd be mad *not* to use closures in LINQ where you need access to the enclosing variables. For example:

```
public List<Person> FilterByAge(IEnumerable<Person> people, int age)
{
    return people.Where(p => p.Age >= age).ToList();
}
```

That lambda expression is a closure, accessing `age` from within a delegate.

As for gotchas:

- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- Generic variance doesn't play well with combining delegates
- Just getting your head round everything :)

Comment: Any performance benefits of the closure? Also, why would I be mad not to use closures in LINQ? Although, I guess there's no other real way to access an enclosing variable in LINQ with the requirement of that code sample.

Comment: @dotnetdev: The alternative is to create a bunch of extra classes just as the compiler does. Bye bye, readability. The performance would be the same, of course, because it's the same code.

Comment: Got ya. Thanks. I guess than, closures are the obvious option.

Comment: And the only other option for closures is to use a standard loop (like for those examples here: http://joe.truemesh.com/blog/000390.html). Either way, the code in a closure is more concise but not really understood by younger coders (just an observation, nothing technically wrong).